# Fetch request not deduplicating on page refresh across generateMetadata() and the layout in Next 13?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, http-headers, next.js13

Fetch requests in Next 13 don't get deduplicated

```
async function fetchData() {
    const c = cookies(),
        at = c.get('at')?.value
    const res = at ? await (await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/fetch`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${at}`
        }
    })).json() : { unauth: !0 }
    if (!res.unauth && res.preferences) return { lang: langs[res.preferences.lang][0], trans: langs[res.preferences.lang][1], ...res }
    const l = c.get('lang')?.value,
        gl = acceptLanguage.get(headers().get('Accept-Language')) || 'en',
        a = c.get('accent')?.value,
        lang = l && langCodes.includes(l) ? parseInt(l) : langIds[gl]
    return {
        preferences: {
            accent: a && accentCodes.includes(a) ? parseInt(a) : 0,
            lang,
            ampm: ampms.includes(lang)
        },
        lang: langs[lang][0], trans: langs[lang][1]
    }
}


export async function generateMetadata(s: any, m: ResolvingMetadata) {
    const {lang} = await fetchData()
    if (typeof lang != 'string') return
    return {other: {lang}}
};

export default async function Layout ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode, locale: any }) {
    const initState = await fetchData()
    return <html lang={initState.lang}>
...
```

This is my root layout code. It is a server component that fetches a user and defines basic params based on the user or on cookies/default values in the case of absence of latter. I also need the generateMetadata function to use the same data. The request uses a JWT token that is retrieved from browser's cookies as an Authorization header. The problem is that the fetch() request gets deduplicated and runs once on the initial load (after server startup), but runs twice every time afterwards.